facetted_pos_scales for date scale
I need to modify my scale_x_date axis after using facet_wrap. So I tried the following code, since I know it works fine for "scale_x_continuous", it doesnt work. Does anyone know, if or how its posible to use facetted_pos_scales (ggh4x package) for a scale_x_date axis?
facetted_pos_scales(x = list(sample_name == 'x' ~ scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2022-07-01"), as.Date("2023-03-01")))))
The whole plot is:
  mutate(match_sp = factor(match_sp, levels = uq.match.sp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.Date(week_sampling), fill = match_sp)) +
  geom_bar(width = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~sample_name+MTOF_diff_med_lab, ncol = 2, scales = "free_x") +
  ggtitle("x")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = vec.man.fill) +
  geom_bar(data = filter(tmp.plot, is.na(match_sp)),
           fill = "grey95", col = "black", width = 5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(c(0,.1), 0))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 month", date_minor_breaks = "week", date_labels = "%b\n%y") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1)) +
  labs(y="Anzahl der Detektionen")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=0.5, size = 7),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),  legend.position = "right",       legend.key.size = unit(0.4, 'cm'))+
  facetted_pos_scales(x = list(sample_name == 'NMDW' ~ scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2022-07-01"), as.Date("2023-03-01")))))```



where's the data? It looks like the first line of your code was cut off.

I can't reproduce this with the economics_long data. Please make the issue reproducible.
